# Git core code managing

Tags: git

I'd like to ask for some advice regarding code managing. I have a project with a core code, code that works for everyone the same. Every client gets his own version of the code with a couple of images replaced and a couple lines of code that are different (like an API URL, server address and update address).

I've been trying this with git branches, but as soon as i change something in the core code, i have to update all git branches with this change, while keeping the per-client changes.

Is there an easier, more elegant way to do this? Or something built into git to do this?

I'm asking this in stack since I have no idea how I would formulate what I want on google.

Comment: You can leave those personal files out of the Git repo, and add them to your `.gitignore` file.  Is there any reason why someone would ever have to sync these non-shared files with the repository?

Comment: There is. It's an app, and other people need to build these as well in case i'm not available to build a new app.

Comment: Either the file is part of the repo, it's not, or it is, but it is somehow ignored.  In any case, you can't have a portion of a file synched and the other portion not synched, in general it's all in or all out with Git.

Comment: That is why i'm asking if there is another way to manage it. The addresses have to exists but are per build/customer different. Also the images have to exists, but are, like the addresses, differen for each build/customer.

Comment: Will these images every become part of the main shared repository?  If they will only ever be local, then consider leaving them out of the repo.

Comment: Can you turn the shared "core" code into a generic library or framework? Then you can have the client-specific variants as separate projects (in separate repositories) that use the core as a dependency they install together with other libraries or frameworks they need.

Comment: See it as logo.png - customer A gets "his own" app with his own logo and app icons, customer B also gets "his own" app, so logo.npg has te be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing code and configuration, not a good thing as you found out.

First, cleanly separate the two, i.e. make sure the code is completely clean of such configuration values (no IP addresses coded inside the actual source code). Remove the options to configuration files and change the code so it gets the values from there.

Now, depending on how many clients you have, you could just have a directory with lots of config files (together with additional files, like the images you mentioned, structured in subdirectory as necessary/practical); at build time, you would just pick one of them. Of course, your build process would not deploy the config files from the other clients.

As long as the files are cleanly separated, you can have them all together in your main branch. I assume you do not deliver your repository to your clients, so there's no security aspect involved here.

Comment: You have me started thinking. The variables that need to change are in a config file in the repo. I could try and make a batch script that copies the config file of the customer into the project and builds it.